# Upper bounding a sum of products

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, asymptotics

Let $a_k$ be an integer valued sequence, $a_k \in \mathbb{N}^+$  and let $b_k = \#\{i: a_i=1,\; i \leq k\}$ and assume that $b_k=o(k)$ (little o notation).

How to prove that there exists a constant $c_+ < \infty$ depending only on $a_k$ s.t. $\forall n\geq 1$:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \prod_{j=0}^ia_j\leq c_+\prod_{i=0}^na_i$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

We know the following: if $l < m$ then

$$\prod_{j=0}^l a_j \leq \prod_{j=0}^m a_j$$

If we choose $c_+ = n$, then the inequality follows immediately. In order to choose $c_+$ using only $a_k$, we can make use of $a_k\in\mathbb{N}^+$, which means $n\leq \sum a_k$. So, choose $c_+ = \sum a_k$ .

I wonder why that $b_k$ business is there. Is it a red herring or something?